# How to show custom annotationView in RMMapview, when tap on the pinpoint?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have been implemented tapOnMarker selector, and create the custom annotationView. and it is showing the annotationView, but when i am clicking to the pinpoint, then annotationView abstract the pinpoint which count is less than to the current pinpoint and pinpoints has max count be showing over the annotationView, here is my implementation code.

```
- (void) tapOnMarker: (RMMarker*) marker onMap: (RMMapView*) map
{
    frame = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbox.png"]];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0,0, 0);
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinMarker.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.enabled = YES;
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(markerLabelButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [marker setLabel:frame];
}
```

Comment: Please add some formatting to your question. It is currently unreadable.

Comment: I need to abstract all pinpoints whcich is cover to the viewAnnotation area??

Answer (score 1):

When you load the marker do these steps:

```
RMMarker *marker = [[RMMarker alloc]initWithUIImage:img anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
[marker setText:@"hello"  forMarker: marker];
[marker hideLabel];

- (void) setText: (NSString*) text forMarker: (RMMarker*) marker
{
  CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont: [RMMarker defaultFont]]; 
  CGPoint position = CGPointMake(  -(textSize.width/2 - marker.bounds.size.width/2), 0 );
  [marker changeLabelUsingText: text position: position font: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 15.0]foregroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor] backgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor]];  
}
```

And whenever you click the marker these method will be called and will show the marker:

```
- (void) tapOnMarker: (RMMarker*) marker onMap: (RMMapView*) map
{
  NSArray* markers = [self.markerManager markers];
  for(RMMarker* m in markers) {
    if ([m class] == [RMMarker class])
      [m hideLabel];
  }
  [marker showLabel];   
}
```